# Uploading XSD schemas with imported namespaces into Marklogic 6

Tags: xsd, marklogic

As a small excercise I'm trying to upload and validate documents with a couple of schemas. These will eventually grow so I'd like to keep them separate.

These example schemas define a localized text string and a food dish:

bitfood-common.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:bfc="http://bitfood.org/common" 
  targetNamespace="http://bitfood.org/common"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="objectId">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="24"/>
      <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:simpleType name="locale">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="5"/>
      <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="localizedText">
    <xs:attribute name="text" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="locale" type="bfc:locale" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

bitfood-dish.xsd:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:bfd="http://bitfood.org/dish" 
  xmlns:bfc="http://bitfood.org/common"
  targetNamespace="http://bitfood.org/dish" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:import namespace="http://bitfood.org/common" 
  schemaLocation="../common/bitfood-common.xsd" />

  <xs:element name="Dish">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="bfc:localizedText" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="description" type="bfc:localizedText" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="id" type="bfc:objectId" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="price" type="xs:decimal" use="required"/>
      <xs:attribute name="imageUrl" type="xs:anyURI" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I then uploaded these two documents inside the Schemas database assigned to my xml database with the following URI id's:

```
schema/common/bitfood-common.xsd
schema/dish/bitfood-dish.xsd
```

And then I uploaded an example document:

dish/520cc720c208c01ddfb75254.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dish id="520cc720c208c01ddfb75254" price="35" 
      imageUrl="FoodCantonGourrmetTwoDish.jpg" 
      xmlns="http://bitfood.org/dish">
  <name text="Example dish." locale="en-US"/>
  <description text="Localized text test." locale="en-US"/>
</Dish>
```

When I issue the following command on the server's query console, I get the empty set when I instruct the database to infer the type of the xml document's root node:

**Update: wrong node index, must be 1 in this case:**

```
(: is it working? :)
declare namespace bfd = "http://bitfood.org/dish";
declare namespace bfc = "http://bitfood.org/common";
xdmp:describe(data(
  doc('dish/520cc720c208c01ddfb75254.xml')/bfd:Dish[1]
))
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results warning="atomic item">xs:untypedAtomic("")</results>
```

This means that the database is either ignoring or not able to find my schema documents. Also, I am not sure if it can't apply the schemas because of the `xs:import namespace` statement.

Has anyone attempted to work with imported XSD documents into Marklogic in this way? Is there anything I may be doing wrong?

**Update 2:** It seems this can only be applied to attributes. The following command does work as expected, which means the schemas are being detected:

```
(: is it working? :)
declare namespace bfd = "http://bitfood.org/dish";
declare namespace bfc = "http://bitfood.org/common";
xdmp:describe(data(doc('dish/520cc720c208c01ddfb75254.xml')/bfd:Dish[1]/@id))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery positional predicates start at 1 not 0.
Try this:

doc('dish/520cc720c208c01ddfb75254.xml')/bfd:Dish[1]

Then work your way up to more complicated code.

-David Lee

Comment: Ah. My bad :P. I think I should also get 8 hours of sleep hehehe.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, changing the index to 1 yields a slightly different result :(  (notice the empty string) <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results warning="atomic item">xs:untypedAtomic("")</results>

Comment: Nevermind. Accessing index 1 did fix the problem. My apologies.